# How to Seperate file name and file path from a string containing Full File Path in perl

Tags: perl

I have a perl program in which there is a variable whose value is the full path of a file.

For example:

```
$FullPath = "C:\sample\file.txt";
```

I want to extract the file name (`file.txt`) in $FileName variable and the path (`C:\sample\`) in `FilePath` variable.

Can anyone please help me to do this with a sample code.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
use File::Basename qw( fileparse );
my ($fname, $dir) = fileparse($FullPath);
```

---

Note that your `$FullPath` doesn't contain `C:\sample\file.txt`. To get that, you need

```
my $FullPath = "C:\\sample\\file.txt";
```

or

```
my $FullPath = 'C:\sample\file.txt';
```

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! It would have warned because of the meaningless `"\s"`.

---

To parse Windows paths on any machine, you can use the following:

```
use Path::Class qw( foreign_file );
my $file = foreign_file('Win32', $FullPath);
my $fname = $file->basename();
my $dir   = $file->dir();
```

Comment: I used the above code which you suggested, but the output is not coming as expected. Output is as follows:                                 $path = "./"                                                                        $name = "C:\sample\file.txt"

Comment: It's cause your code is buggy. You don't actually put `C:\sample\file.txt` in `$FullPath`. See update.

Comment: actually there is a html page in which a file is selected using the browse button, and when the submit button is pressed, the value should be passed to the perl program. so when i am selecting a file using the browse button , and the submit button is pressed, the value being passed to the perl program is "C:\sample\file.txt". but i only want the file name. so can u plz suggest some method to do this??

Comment: Regarding the update to your comment, you appear to be on a unix system, where `C:\sample\file.txt` means a file named `C:\sample\file.txt` in the current directory (`.`).

Comment: Will it always be a Windows path? If so, see update. If not, it's impossible unless you know which type of system it is.

Comment: ya, i am using a windows machine, so it will always be a windows path.

Comment: where to include use strict; and use warnings; in the perl program. i wrote these 2 lines at the top , but when i run, it shows, internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `splitpath` from `File::Spec::Functions`. This function returns the volume, the directories, and the file name as three separate values.

The code below puts these values into an array, then removes the second (directories) element and appends it to the first, giving the full path and the file name as you require in `@path`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions 'splitpath';

my $full_path = 'C:\sample\file.txt';
my @path = splitpath $full_path;
$path[0] .= splice @path, 1, 1;

print "$_\n" for @path;
```

**output**

```
C:\sample\
file.txt
```